# Stop AsyncTask doInBackground Method in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm facing an issue with `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` method, I don't know how to stop this method from running.

I'm working on an application that has a login screen which retrieves information about the logged user. The problem is when I enter a wrong password or username and then when I re-enter the correct data, my application crashes and I get

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has
>   already been executed"

How can I stop this thread from running? Here is the code:

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements LoginParser.GetLoginListener{


    public LoginParser parser1;
    public EditText ETUsername;
    public  EditText ETPassword;
    //private LoginParser lb;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


      parser1 = new LoginParser();

        ETUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET1);
        ETPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET2);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBut);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String UserName = ETUsername.getText().toString();
                String Password = ETPassword.getText().toString();
                Log.e("LoginAct .. userName: ", UserName);
                Log.e("LoginAct .. Password: ", Password);

                if (UserName.isEmpty() || Password.isEmpty()) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).setTitle("Warning")
                            .setMessage("Please Enter your Username and Password")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

                else{

                    parser1.getLoginInfo(UserName, Password);
                    parser1.setListener(LoginActivity.this);
                }
            } // end of button on click
        } );
}

    @Override
    public void didReceivedUserInfo(String displayName) {

        if(displayName != null) {

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).setTitle("Welcome").setMessage("Welcome " + displayName)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        Intent in = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(in);
                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }

                else {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).setTitle("Warning")
                            .setMessage("Error in login ID or Password, Please try again later")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            }).show();
                }
  }
}
```

**LoginParser.java**

```
  public class LoginParser extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String> {

    private String requestURL;

    public  String UserName ;
    public  String Password ;



    public interface GetLoginListener
    {
        public void didReceivedUserInfo (String displayName);
    }

    private GetLoginListener listener;


    public GetLoginListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListener(GetLoginListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    public void getLoginInfo(String userName , String password)
    {
        requestURL = "some link";

        this.UserName = userName ;
        this.Password = password ;

        execute(); // it will call doInBackground in secondary thread
    }




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            String jsonString = "LID="+ UserName +"&PWD="+Password+"&Passcode=****";
            Log.e("LoginParser","JSONString: " + jsonString);


            urlConnection1.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection1.setRequestMethod("POST");
           urlConnection1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             urlConnection1.setRequestProperty("charset","utf-8");


            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection1.getOutputStream());
            // out.print(this.requestMessage);
            out.print(jsonString);
            out.close();

            int statusCode = urlConnection1.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("statusCode", String.valueOf(statusCode));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] data = null;

            if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection1.getInputStream()));

                String line;

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }

                data = response.toString().getBytes();
            }

            else {

                data = null;// failed to fetch data
            }

            String responseString = new String(data);
            Log.e("doInBackground", "responseString" + responseString);

            JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(responseString);
            String Status = jsonObject2.getString("Status");
            Log.e("Status", Status);

            if (Status.equals("s")) {


                Log.i("Status:", "Successful");

                String displayName = jsonObject2.getString("DisplayName");


                return displayName;
            }

            else {

                return null;

            }

        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String displayName) {
        super.onPostExecute(displayName);

        Log.e("onPost: ","onPost");
        listener.didReceivedUserInfo(displayName);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "can't re-execute task" error can be solved by creating a new instance of the AsyncTask.  You can't call execute twice on the same instance, but you can make as many instances as you want.

Stopping the execution won't help that error.  The problem isn't that its currently running, the problem is that you need to create a new instance and run that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel Async task using continuous check of isCancel in your doInBackground method.

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Hope this will help you.